# Какая грамматическая основа? (2)

Tags: синтаксис, грамматика, подлежащее, инфинитив

*Попытки вырастить сорта оканчивались неудачей*.

Объясните, пожалуйста, где тут подлежащее. "Попытки" или "попытки вырастить"?

Answer (score 3):

***Попытки** вырастить сорта **оканчивались** неудачей.*

Подлежащее – *попытки,* сказуемое – *оканчивались,*
*вырастить* – определение.

> В русском синтаксисе неопределенная форма глагола, или **инфинитив**, может быть любым членом предложения.
>
> Глагол в начальной форме может пояснять существительное. Тогда он является **несогласованным определением.**
>
> **Примеры предложений:**
> *Ее манера (какая?) говорить полушёпотом раздражала меня.*
> *Стремление (какое?) выжить в этих экстремальных условиях не покидало нас.*
> *Умение (какое?) фантазировать было у неё с самого детства.*

Источник: [**poisk2.ru**](https://poisk2.ru/glagol-vystupayuschiy-v-roli-dopolneniya-primery/).

Comment: Александр, вы не подскажете, как отличать синтаксически неделимые словосочетания от обычных. По словарю слово «попытка» требует обязательного распространителя (действие, направленное на осуществление или достижение ЧЕГО-ЛИБО).
Синтаксическая неделимость большинства словосочетаний объясняется семантической недостаточностью их главного слова (попытка).  В Студопедии дается перечень таких сочетаний и даже способ проверки: склон горы — горный склон (это обычное сочетание, можно заменить согласованным определением).

Comment: Каков же статус слова «попытка», да и других слов, требующих обязательных распространителей? Как здесь не ошибиться?
https://studopedia.ru/3_79363_ponyatie-chlenimih-i-nechlenimih-slovosochetaniy-osnovnie-priznaki-nechlenimih-slovosochetaniy.html

Comment: Словарная формулировка вовсе не указывает на *обязательность* распространителя. Так можно почти любое слово отнести к лексически недостаточным: *работать*  – заниматься КАКИМ-ЛИБО делом, действовать ЧЕМ-ЛИБО;  *умение* – способность выполнять КАКУЮ-ЛИБО работу, делать ЧТО-ЛИБО.  Перечня неделимых сочетаний по вашей ссылки не нашел, там только примеры. Как различать делимые и неделимые словосочетания не всегда понятно, а иногда и субъективно. По мне так *попытка*  – "нормальное" слово.  Но скорее всего, вы правы и дадите свой ответ. А я свой удалю.

Comment: Я не собираюсь отвечать, потому что НЕ ЗНАЮ (и еще мои ответы мне НАДОЕЛИ, все бы стерла).  Для меня это вообще давняя проблема, а сейчас она как-то обострилась. Многие сочетания кажутся синтаксически неделимыми, да и перечни у всех разные. В общем, полная дезориентация в теме. Вот я и надеялась на вашу помощь.  Обязательность распространителя я определяю по вопросу в словарной статье (иногда он есть, а иногда его нет), да и то не уверена в термине.

Comment: Больше всего меня умиляют такие синтаксически неделимые сочетания, как котенок с белыми лапками и собака с большими ушами.  Это тоже как бы подлежащее, а по-моему,  это крайний грамматический формализм. Почему я не могу считать, что это несогласованные определения? К тому же их всегда можно обособить, и тогда сочетание сразу станет  синтаксически делимым. Извините, если я вам надоедаю не по делу – возможно, это вам совсем неинтересно.

Comment: Нет, наоборот, интересно. Сижу, копаюсь, одно за другое цепляется... уже и не по теме куда-то нырнул... всякие *комтаминации* и *дескриптивизмы*, ха-ха-ха